# What does the error "Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure()." mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am new to flutter and watned to create my first app.

I installed Flutter. I tested it using `flutter doctor` and got no errors. I created a new app using `flutter create my_app`. In the app directory I ran `flutter build apk` and got the following error back.

```
C:\Users\Username\StudioProjects\my_app3> flutter build apk

 Building with sound null safety


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
> Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         2.560ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: LOL same here! I am starting to believe that frontend is really hating me!

Comment: Me, on linux, from Android Studio, freshly "minted" app. Doctor is all green, of course.

Comment: Try this: Go to "Android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties" and change the distributionUrl to https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip. Then, Flutter clean and aFlutter pub get on terminal and should be fixed.